# Update by an index and a mask?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, updates, mask

I have a big 2-dimensional array which I access by indexes. I want to update only the values of the indexed array which are not zero.

```
arrayx = np.random.random((10,10))
```

Let's say I have indexes (this is just example, the actual indexes are generated by separate process):

```
idxs = np.array([[4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8]]), np.array([[5, 9]])
```

Given these indexes, this should work, but it doesn't.

```
arrayx[idxs]

array([[0.7 , 0.1 ],
       [0.79, 0.51],
       [0.  , 0.8 ],
       [0.82, 0.32],
       [0.82, 0.89]], dtype=float16)

// note from editor: '<>' is equivalent to '!='
// but I agree that '>' 0 is more correct
// mask = mapx[idxs] <> 0 // original
mask = arrayx[idxs] > 0 // better

array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])

arrayx[idxs][mask] += 1
```

However, this does not update the array. How can I solve this?

Comment: so your map's 2D and indexes have a weird shape can you please update your question with proper data? I mean you have something understandable for map but not for idxs

Comment: also, you should probably avoid using `map` as a variable name as it would overwrite python's buil-in map function

Comment: Is your goal to update `mapx` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with a mask as the first input to choose and assign -

```
mapx[idxs] = np.where(mask,mapx[idxs]+1,mapx[idxs])
```

**Custom update values**

The second argument (here `mapx[idxs]+1`) could be edited to any complex update that you might be doing for the masked places corresponding to `True` ones in `mask`. So, let's say you were doing an update for the masked places with :

```
mapx[idxs] += x * (A - mapx[idxs])
```

Then, replace the second arg to `mapx[idxs] + x * (A - mapx[idxs])`.

---

Another way would be to extract integer indices off `True` ones in `mask` and then create new `idxs` that is selective based on the mask, like so -

```
r,c = np.nonzero(mask)
idxs_new = (idxs[0][:,0][r], idxs[1][0][c])
mapx[idxs_new] += 1
```

The last step could be edited similarly for a custom update. Just use `idxs_new` in place of `idxs` to update.

Comment: i simplified the update is not simple += 1, but a complex formula !

Comment: @sten Could that complex formula be put as something involving `mapx[idxs]`? If so, then just replace that complex formula with the second arg to `np.where`?

Comment: yep.. mapx[idxs] += x * (A - mapx[idxs])

Comment: @sten So, just replace the second arg to `np.where` to that : `mapx[idxs] + x * (A - mapx[idxs])`.

Comment: oo i see never used .where() like this... checked the docs :)